# MVC и PHP. Входные данные.

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Более-менее разобрался с MVC по [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/) на хабре. понял, что контроллер выводит данные, добытые из модели в вид. Но как быть с приемом данных? принимать их обратно через тот же контроллер и сохранять через ту же модель? Как можно сделать админку на этой структуре? что если создать другую точку входа в папке admin и логиниться через htpasswd? или это противоречит системе? Короче, прошу всех, кто что знает об этом поведать, ссылки на статьи приветствуются, варианты авторизации тоже.

Answer (score 1):

**Модель**, определенно, должна быть та же. Незачем плодить новые модели.

**Контроллер** можете создать другой, разместить его в папке `admin` и назначить на него иные требования (вроде авторизации или доступа с определенного IP - что душе угодно).

Или же создать у существующего контроллера, который отвечает за этот функционал, новый **метод**, повесить его на другой маршрут и т.д. Зависит от системы.

**Авторизация**, тем более, зависит от системы. Можете добавить какие-то методы, вроде `beforeAction` и вызывать их перед вызовом метода контроллера (если можете это сделать) - там и проверяйте свою авторизацию.
Или повесьте проверку авторизации на **маршрут**, который начинается с `/admin/..`.

Answer (score 0):

контроллер и принимает данные от пользователя, и делает с ними что вам надо

вот пример с yii фрэймфорка

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
...

/**
* Displays a particular model.
* @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
*/
public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
  }
...
}
```

Comment: тот же контроллер, что и выводит данные? можно пример, хотя бы простейший?